# Possible to Implement Baseband OFDM on Microcontroller?

Tags: ofdm

I am wondering if one can implement OFDM on any available microcontroller or Development board in the present Market. Definitely not looking FPGA solution. Specifically, on any Microcontroller is it possible?

Comment: What rates and frequencies?  I've done audio sample rate OFDM on Raspberry Pi's and old iPhones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OFDM is just math; an OFDM receiver is just an algorithm. As a microcontroller is a universal computer (i.e. equivalent to a Turing machine), it can execute any algorithm. So, the answer is yes.

Whether or not it is performant enough / has enough memory for the specific OFDM system you have in mind is something nobody can tell you without knowing exactly what kind of OFDM system, what performance bounds and what microcontroller you have in mind.